# How to post data to a page and navigate to another page in php

Tags: php

I'm posting data to a page and after that I want to navigate to another page at the same  time. I'm using a javascript to post the data and I checked it be echoing its values and it works fine when I send only post data but when I'm redirecting to another page and try to access those post data it seems to be not set. 
and by the way what I have written is a javascript like this

```
function getsupport ( selectedtype )
```

{
  document.folderCreation.supporttype.value = selectedtype ;
  document.folderCreation.submit() ;
  document.location.href="../../index.php";

}

and in the form :

```
<form action="index.php" name="folderCreation" method="POST" >
      <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" /><?php
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
  {
      $filePath=$row['pathFromImages']; 
      $id=$row['id'];
      ?>

      <a href="javascript:getsupport('<?php  echo $filePath;?>')" ><?php echo $filePath;?></a>
      </br>

<?php
```

this form values are posted correctly when the line :document.location.href="../../index.php"; is not there. Why is this not working?..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please accept answers on your old posts, to increase your chances of getting an answer on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code should work:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="a" onsubmit="postdata($(this)); return true;" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

javascript function:

```
function postdata(x){ $.post('page1.php', {a: x.a.val()}); }
```